# Error in simple bash script - mv + awk

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have attempted to write a script that renames a list of directories in a folder. It is a bash script and I am only using awk to accomplish this task.

Current form:

```
[2015] Name of the album
```

Desired form:

```
Name of the album - [2015]
```

My script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
for f in \[*; do
    mv -t "$f" "$( awk -F '\] ' ' {print $2 " - " $1 "]"}' <<<"$f" )"
done
```

When I execute the above script, I get the following error:

```
mv: cannot stat 'In Dreams [EP] - [1963]': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want `-t` in your situation.  That will tell `mv` to try to move the desired name to the directory named `$f`.

It would expand to something like:

```
mv -t "[2015] Name of the album" "Name of the album - [2015]"
```

which would be likely what you want without the `-t`.  As is it treats `$f` as the target directory name into which all the other arguments should be moved.

Comment: Amazing! I removed the -t option and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to `perl-rename` (called `rename` on Debian based systems including Ubuntu, `perl-rename` on Arch and `prename` on others), you can do:

```
perl-rename -n 's/(\[.*?\])\s*(.*)/$2 - $1/' ./\[*
```

#### Explanation

- `-n` : this makes `perl-rename` print what it will do without actually renaming anything. Run it like this and, if it looks like it's working as expected, remove the `-n` to make it actually rename.
- `s/from/to/` : will replace `from` with `to`.
- `s/(\[.*?\])\s*(.*)/$2 - $1/'` : here, the `from` is everything between the first `[` and the first `]` (`\[.*?\]`). Then 0 or more whitespace characters (`\s*`) and then everything else (`.*`). The parentheses around the patters will *capture* them, letting us use them as `$1` and `$2` respectively on the right hand side of the substitution. So, that will put everything after the `[ ]` (`$2`) before the brackets (`$1`).
- `./\[*` run it on all files and directories in the current directory whose name begins with a `[`.

Answer (score 4):

Your solution works if you remove the `-t` option, as Eric explained.

This is an alternative solution using variable substitutions rather than `awk` to move the bits of the filename around:

```
for name in '['*; do
    tag="${name%% *}"
    title="${name#* }"
    mv "$name" "$title - $tag"
done
```

- `${name%% *}` removes everything after the first space in `$name` (including the space), and
- `${name#* }` removes everything before the first space (including the space).